# Heterogeneous type mappings detected when making new array in LINQ Npgsql Dot Net 6

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I upgraded my `dotnet5 web api` to `dotnet6` since then I am getting the error `Heterogeneous type mappings detected when making new array` whereas the same is working in `dotnet5`.

Below is my query

```
var a = (from i in _context.Items
        join t in _context.ItemAttrs on i.itemCode equals t.itemCode into temp
        from ia in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
        join t1 in _context.BarCodes on ia.id equals t1.itemAttrID into temp1
        from b in temp1.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new
        {
            label = $"{i.itemDesc} | {ia.addlUoM} | {b.barCodeOrShortCode}", // working
            label2 = $"{i.itemDesc} | {ia.addlUoM} | M-{ia.mRP.ToString()}", // working
            label3 = $"{i.itemDesc} | M-{ia.mRP} | {b.barCodeOrShortCode}", // working
            label4 = $"{i.itemDesc} | {ia.addlUoM} | M-{ia.mRP} | {b.barCodeOrShortCode}", // NOT WORKING
            
            ... other props
        }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Here, `itemDesc, addlUoM, barCodeOrShortCode are string and mRP is decimal`. And `b` is `nullable`.

Any breaking change for this in `dotnet6`?

Comment: Not what you are asking, but you do not have to do `.ToString()` inside the `{}` of an interpolated string. So `$"... {ia.mRP} ... "` is enough.

Comment: `true` @JeppeStigNielsen